# Tag Img nao renderiza imagem da pasta local assets

Tags: react

[image: tag imagem nao é renderizada na tela]

Não consigo acessar a imagem, não aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em [react](/questions/tagged/react) imagens devem ser importadas quando o arquivo for local, um exemplo claro:

```
import img from './assets/BeTheHero.png';
```

e na parte do código passar essa variável

```
<img src={img} />
```

e vale lembrar que a imagem deve ficar dentro da pasta `src` para que isso funcione.

Vários outros exemplos:

- [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)
- [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images/45526690)
- [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)
- [How to import image (.svg, .png ) in a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823289/how-to-import-image-svg-png-in-a-react-component)
- [importing images with React](https://www.edwardbeazer.com/importing-images-with-react/)
- [Load local images in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js)

Comment: mas no caso teria como eu pegar esses caminhos por props?

Comment: pq to qrendo uma pagina q as imagens vao se alterar de acordo com o botao

Comment: @JuvenalBrunoAndrade pode sim, mas, a sua inicial pergunta foi respondida e o site funciona assim. Bom pode abrir um novo questionamento e melhorar o exemplo minimo. Se essa resposta foi suficiente para responder sua pergunta inicial por favor assinale como respostas